# Segmentation fault (core dumped) - C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This is part of program, where I need to know if arguments  are int. I can't understand why I have this error 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'.

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    int i = 1;
    while(i < argc)
    {
        if(isdigit(argv[i]))
            printf("OK\n");
        else
            printf("NOT OK\n"); 
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `argv[i]` is of type `char *`, and `isdigit()` wants `int` (or `char` - just a single character).

Comment: @Jens Too late. I had fixed my comment before you've posted yours.

Comment: I don't get a segfault here

Comment: As noted under one of the answers, it is indeed a problem. But I don't see why would it cause segfault. Show the other code.

Comment: To correct the above, the standard *does* demand the argument to be represantable as unsigned `char` or `EOF`: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4p1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for.

```
 int main(int argc,char* argv[])
    {
        int i = 1;
        int j;
        while(i < argc)
        {
            j = 0;
            while (argv[i][j] != 0)
            {
                if(isdigit(argv[i][j]))
                    printf("OK\n");
                else
                    printf("NOT OK\n"); 
                j++;  
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```

argv[i] is pointer, not a data. You're passing a pointer where a `char` (i think) is expected.

You should compile your file using the warnings flags with `gcc` : `-w -Wall -Wextra` it will tell you that you're passing the wrong type of argument.

If is digit takes an `int` you've have to convert the `argv[i][j]` into an int with `atoi(argv[i][j])`

Comment: You don't need to convert the character. `isdigit()` can take an argument like: `'5'` and then, return `true`. *each character has integer ascii value*

Comment: If the value of your argument is `7`(exemple) print its value with this `printf("%d\n", argv[1][0]) it will give you 55. Because ` each character has integer ascii value` but this is not the `decimal` value of your argv[1][0].

Comment: and now I have a different problem. I have task make a simple calc. write number and signs like arguments and solve it. I want to check which argument is number and which is sign. with 2 loops I can check only separated character. does it exist some way to check whole argument?

Comment: Yes ! try `isdigit(atoi(argv[i]))` in only 1 while loop. Can you please validate now :D @CrapdoTwothausand

Comment: @CrapdoTwothausand atoi will convert the whole string `argv[i]` like `1234` into an int and `isdigit` will take the whole number

Comment: @NicolasGuerin I try isdigit(atoi(argv[i])) and for some reason it return false. I try to add also another check isalpha and I have segmentation error again.

Answer (score 1):

`isdigit()` takes an `int` as argument, but here you pass a `char *`.
So, you have to make a loop on each string:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    int i = 1;
    int j;
    while(i < argc)
    {
        j = -1;
        while (argv[i][++j] != 0)
        {
            if(isdigit(argv[i][j]))
                printf("OK\n");
            else
                printf("NOT OK\n"); 
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`argv[i]` is a ptr-to-char, but `isdigit()` takes an `int`. No wonder the program crashes. Did you mean to use `isdigit(argv[x][y])` somehow?

Comment: Actually there is a wonder it is crashing. pointers are safely converted to `int`.

Comment: @eugenesh: but it is no longer safe if that int is used as an index into a small array. How do you expect that `isdigit` works?

Comment: @rici It can very well check the ranges. I haven't found any mentioning of UB in this function based on the value passed. So I would say the implementation which is segfaulting is non-conforming.

Comment: @EugeneSh. From my man page: "The value of the argument must be representable as an unsigned char or the value of EOF."

Comment: The standard is not mentioning it. At least I haven't found it.

Comment: Actually I have found it. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4p1 . Sorry everyone :)

Comment: @eugene: checking the ranges goes against the C philosophy. If you are unconfident about the validity of an argument you are about to pass, it is up to you to do the check, so that those of us who have ensured correctness don't have to pay the price of an unnecessary check. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`argv[i]` has `char*` type, but `isdigit()` expects `int` (ASCII code of `char` is being casted to `int` automatically).

Write separate function to check if string contains digits only.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_string_number(const char* str)
{
    while (*str)
    {
        if (!isdigit(*str++))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
        printf(is_string_number(argv[i]) ? "OK\n" : "NOT OK\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Print the char casted you'll see that this the ascii value that is passed in `isdigit` and not the decimal value.

Comment: I don't say that `'0'` is being casted to `0`. But `char` is being casted to `int` automatically while some calculations or passing as argument.

Comment: Yeah but it could leave to mistakes. If he starts thinking that you can cast char to int without problemes. I didn't say you post is wrong just make sure that everything is said

`(char is being casted automatically).` if you could add with ascii value not decimal or something like that :)